# Como fazer um switch em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, switch

Como posso fazer um `switch` em Ruby?

Comment: Poderia apresentar algum esforço de pesquisa.

Comment: Vários exemplos: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-can-i-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby

Comment: Não sei porque tem gente dando down vote para a pergunta da @mayra. É uma dúvida que muitos iniciantes tem, e pode ser útil para bastante gente, pois pra quem vem de outras linguagens é bem diferente.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neste caso o Ruby utliza a estrutura `case...when`

```
case objeto
when 1
  puts "Seu número é 1"
when 2..10
  puts "Seu número está entre 2 e 10"
when 11,13,17,19
  puts "é um número primo entre 10 e 20"
when String
  puts "é uma String"
else
  puts "Qualquer outra coisa."
end
```

Você pode criar essa estrutura sem parâmentro também

```
case
when objeto < 10
  puts "Menor que 10"
when objeto == 10
  puts "Igual a 10"
when (10..20) === b
  puts "Alguma coisa entre 10 e 20"
end
```

E também o Ruby interpreta todo tipo de instrução como o `case when/ if else` enfim... Ou seja:

```
    objeto = 1
    variable_to_return = case objeto
                           when 1
                             10
                           else 
                             'UAHEUHAUEHUAEHUAE sou uma String!'
                         end
   puts variable_to_return  # => 10
```

Comment: Obrigada Luiz Carvalho